# pg_badger report is empty?

Tags: postgresql, pgbadger

Using pg badger to generate daily reports of the database but the report is empty ? ANy ideas why?

thanks

```
log_min_duration_statement = -1 
log_duration = on
log_line_prefix = '%t [%p]: user=%u,db=%d,app=%a,client=%h' 
log_checkpoints = 'on'
 log_lock_waits = 'on' 
log_temp_files = 0 
log_autovacuum_min_duration = 0 
log_error_verbosity = 'default' 
lc_messages='en_US.UTF-8'
```

> -bash-4.2$ pgbadger -f stderr -d dbdev /var/lib/pgsql/13/data/log/postgresql-*.log -x html -o
> /var/lib/pgsql/13/data/log/pgbadger_dbdevv_`date +\%F`.html
> [========================>] Parsed 23526878 bytes of 23526878
> (100.00%), queries: 0, events: 0 LOG: Ok, generating html report...

Answer (score 0):

The [pgBadger documentation](https://pgbadger.darold.net/documentation.html#POSTGRESQL-CONFIGURATION) states:

> You must first enable SQL query logging to have something to parse:
>
> `log_min_duration_statement = 0`

Comment: the sessions tab is still empty wit no values?